# retrieve old cached version of a css file?

Tags: css, google-chrome, magento-go

I'm kind of experiencing an emergency, where I'm using a "magento go" platform and wanted to upload my own css file.  However, what I didn't understand is that it OVERWRITES the current css file of my site.

Is there a way that I can look back through my chrome browser's css files cached from this afternoon in order to see the site from what it once looked like and move from there?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help you: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/recover-cache-files-google-chrome-28533.html

Comment: @Fahad Hasan,Thanks,It was really fantastic,Here is another way :https://gist.github.com/minhajuddin/1504425